# Speech recognition tool for gaming

Tags: windows-8, speech-recognition, voice-command, gaming

I'm looking for a speech recognition software for gaming. The goal is to control my computer with my voice by emulating my keyboard or joystick/gamepad.

I'm working/playing on Windows 8. The software should accept complex scripting to emulate more than just a key pressed. I want to work with variables. Most voice recognition software are too limited. They can just emulate a simple keyboard or keypad key.

These critere are a plus:

- Free software
- Open source

Comment: Are there any specific requirements? What OS must be supported? Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I think that speech recognition is not that useful in gaming. Especially for real time gaming. It would be really frustrating if You need a command fast, and your voice doesn't get recognized, or it misunderstands something and does something else than that You wanted. Another thing is the latency. Voice recognition will always go with delay. If I were You, I would concentrate on something different, like motion detection. That can be cool in games. Just my opinion.

Comment: Well... Try X-Wing vs T-Fighter with voice recognition or Homeword with voice recognition or Silent Hunter with voice recognition or give order in Arma or operation flashpoint with voice recognition, Try Counter Strike, Day of Defeat for orders with voice recongnition. Of course you shouldn't use voice recongtion to move or fire but you can use it to give orders and it is pretty fast. can be faster than than searching for the correct order.